# Need opinion on this web design FOR UX/UI/CX - Beginner in designing

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, html, css

[image]

[image]

Hi, first of all, sorry if I'm posting in the wrong section. I want to get an opinion about the design of an event management system. I've google on UX example design but most only show for simple thing like registration and login so I'm at lost for this.

This is an event registration form,

"Majlis Konvokesyen" is supposed to be the event name and underneath it is the event date. This 2 will only shows up if user has registered an event before.

"Halaman Permohonan" is the page title.

"1. Maklumat Pemohon" is basic information of the user that is applying for an event.

"2. MAKLUMAT Permohonan" is the event information such as involving parties, location of event, date of event, time of event and summary of event.

Is it wrong to do it like this? If it is, how should I fix it?

My company doesn't have a real designer so I'm at lost as to who I should ask and decided to try here. I really want to improve my designing skill so any tips/comment/critics is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to break what your doing down into parts, ask specific questions about some of those parts.

Comment: @straya thanks for the reply. I'll give that a try. Is it bad breaking the form into section and then each section get its own tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this looks very complicated for registering to the event. Can you remove some of the required fields. Challenge the absolute minimum amount of needed information entry and steps. Why do you need something else than than picking an event and entering your email address?

Secondly the navigation seems odd, there is double navigation (hambuger and side menu), that seems to be very unorthodox.

Thridly, you can improve this design a lot by just using space better, with slightly better visual design. If giving this to to a proficient visual designer for 2 hours is too expensive, you could do self-study, with these practical resources:

- [https://www.amazon.com/Dont-Make-Me-Think-Usability/dp/0321344758](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)
- https://refactoringui.com/

Fourthly, you should design the mobile version first, to keep it as simple as possible. Doing the desktop version first on big screen is a surefire way to make the UX bad on mobile.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply sir. I'll definitely check the links. As for the many input, it is whats required by the user but I'll try to see if anything can be remove. As for double navigation, the burger button is actually linked to the side menu, which is to close/open the sidemenu. But now that you mention it, I think it is stupid to put in on the desktop version. I think I might hide it depending on the screen size. As for using space better, I absolutely have no idea what you're talking about T_T. I'm just so stupid at designing plus with my lack of experience. This is my first job.

Comment: Yes, it is visually separated from side menu, so it looks like it is another navigation.